# Плохо ли использовать одну глобальную константу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. 
Пишу программу в которой у меня есть логин и пароль для каждого пользователя + права доступа.
Вот у меня вопрос. Мне нужно на протяжении всей программы хранить права доступа пользователя.
Права доступа используются в разных классах функциях и файлах программы.
Мне кажется самым простым решением создать одну глобальную константу в которой будут храниться права доступа.
Но слышал что глобальные переменные зло. Но не передавать из класса в класс переменную в которой будет написано "admin" или "work".
Скажите что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Why is Global State so Evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108/1985)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python: How to make a cross-module variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/142545/4279)—django settings пример.

Кратко: если переменная после инициализации программы не меняется, то вполне оправдано глобальный config объект, получаемый по вызову функции иметь (последнее чтобы тестовый config легче было заводить). Ещё пример: [create_app() для flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/appfactories/).

Answer (score 3):

ИМХО идеальным вариантом будет вынести код для проверок прав доступа из отдельных методов с специальный класс (ACL). При создании объекта acl передавать ему логин/пароль/права доступа, всё что может потребоваться для вычисления прав. И уже этот объект передавать из класса в класс.

Но проектировать api и структуру такой махины - довольно сложно и занимает кучу времени. Если вы делаете прототип или что-либо вроде proof-of-concept, то вполне подойдут и глобальные переменные, лижбы это работало и можно было "потыркать".

Плюсы ACL:

1. Легче теститьвать
2. Можно отдельно тестирьвать ACL и методы доступа/изменения данных
3. Проще модифицировать (добавлять новые роли/типы пользователей).
4. Проще повторно использовать.

Минусы:

1. Нужно передавать в каждый класс который хочет работать с парвами (решается через DI)
2. Требует больше сил на первоначальное создание (проектирование api, возможность расширения ...)

Плюсы глобальной переменной:

1. Нет необходимости делать DI.
2. Нет необходимости заранее продумывать API для пользователей
3. Можно сразу начинать фигачить код :)

Минусы:

1. Тестировать код который зависит от глобального (внешнего) состояния значительно сложнее.
2. Меньше возможностей повторно использовать (если есть несколько методов работающих с одним и темже объектом, то код проверки доступа придётся дублировать)
3. Если код проверки прав, размазан по всему проекту, то добавить новый тип пользователя будет значительно сложнее.